# What's wrong in this allocation?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

This the struct that I declared :-

```
struct page_table_entry {
    struct addrspace* as;
    vaddr_t va;
    //page_state_t state;
    int timestamp;
};
```

Now I want to dynamically allocate memory for an array of this. My implementation is here :-

```
struct page_table_entry **coremap = (struct page_table_entry**)
kmalloc(npages*sizeof(struct page_table_entry*));
int i;
for(i=0;i<npages;i++)
{
    coremap[i] = (struct page_table_entry*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct page_table_entry));
    coremap[i].va=(firstAddress+(i*PAGE_SIZE));
}
```

Its giving me an error on the last line where I am accesing the variable va. Error is:-

```
error: request for member `va' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: Oh!! you are right. Was stressing a bit too much on the allocation that I didn't pay much attention to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of pointers to structs, not an array of structs.

In the line
    coremap[i] = (struct page_table_entry*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct page_table_entry));
you cast your memory allocation to `page_table_entry*`, so coremap[i] is this pointer.

You access the actual struct via

```
coremap[i]->va=(firstAddress+(i*PAGE_SIZE));
```

Answer (score 1):

`coremap` is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct page_table_entry`.

When you dereference it with `coremap[i]` you get a pointer to a `struct page_table_entry`.

You cannot use `.` on a pointer to a structure. You must use `->`:

```
coremap[i]->va=(firstAddress+(i*PAGE_SIZE));
```

or

```
(*coremap[i]).va=(firstAddress+(i*PAGE_SIZE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious change to `coremap[i]->va`, you could change to an array of structs:

```
struct page_table_entry *coremap = (struct page_table_entry*)kmalloc(npages*sizeof(struct page_table_entry));
int i;
for(i=0;i<npages;i++)
{
    coremap[i].va=(firstAddress+(i*PAGE_SIZE));
}
```